# How to change [ "3", ".", "1"] into [3.1]

Tags: python

Basically I have a list of strings, and for the "floats" I have indentified, I want to turn them into actual floats. So when my code discovers "10" , ".", "5" I want to turn that into just 10.5

So I tried keeping track of 2 index's. The starting one (a) and the ending one (n). So index a would be "3" and n would be "1".

Also there are other items in my list besides these characters such as brackets

```
def splitter(string):
    a=0
    s = list(string)
    for n, i in enumerate(s):
        if isinstance(i,float):
            break
        if i.isdigit():
            if s[n+1] != "." :
                    s[n] = float("i")
            if s[n+1] == "." :
                a = n[:]
                while s[n+1].isdigit() or s[n+1] == ".":
                    n+=1

    return s
```

So now I am stumped as to where to go from here. Obviously s[a:n] = float(s[a:n]) because there are commas in the way

Comment: Is everything in your list a single final number? Or are there more items in the list?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to also show your expected output for a few possible examples.

Comment: maybe you should use modules for tokenization like [PLY - Python Lex Yacc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html)

Comment: The code in it's current format cannot work since it has syntax errors beginning with `float("i")` @Will First you need to fix those :) Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

def tokenization(expr):
    return [float(i) if re.search(r"\d+\.?\d*", i) else i for i in re.split('([^a-zA-Z0-9\.])', expr) if i.strip()]

print(tokenization("(3.1+ 6*2∧2)*(2 - 1)"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should return 
`return [float(''.join(s))]`

Comment: That's not a float. Its a string.

Comment: oh i see, i'll fix

Comment: oh if u have more items, than my code is wrong, i'll take a look into

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a list with float element.

```
[float(''.join(s))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code has some issues

- `s[n] = float("i")` should change to  `s[n] = float(i)` I assume, since you want to convert `i` into a float
- `a = n[:]` is wrong, since you are trying to splice an index `n` and assign it to `a`,  I assume you wanted to do `a = s[:]`, also you are not using `a` anywhere

After fixing this issues, the code changes to

```
def tokenization(expr):
    a=0
    s = list(expr)
    for n, i in enumerate(s):
        if isinstance(i,float):
            break
        if i.isdigit():
            if s[n+1] != "." :
                    #Changed this line
                    s[n] = float(i)
            if s[n+1] == "." :
                # Changed this line
                a = s[:]
                while s[n+1].isdigit() or s[n+1] == ".":
                    n+=1

    return s


print(tokenization("(3.1+ 6*2∧2)*(2 - 1)"))
```

And the output is

```
['(', '3', '.', 1.0, '+', ' ', 6.0, '*', 2.0, '∧', 2.0, ')', '*', '(', 2.0, ' ', '-', ' ', 1.0, ')']
```

which is expected since each numerical digit is converted to float and shown

I would suggest using a regex to find the floats

```
import re

def tokenization(expr):
    return [float(item) if re.search(r"\d+\.?\d*", item) else item for item in re.findall(r'[()]|[^\w]+|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', expr)]

print(tokenization("(3.1+ 6*2∧2)*(2 - 1)"))
```

Output is `['(', 3.1, '+ ', 6.0, '*', 2.0, '∧', 2.0, ')', '*(', 2.0, ' - ', 1.0, ')']`

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without regex. Just a loop, storing digits and dots in a reserved list `nmb` to later convert them to float. It also skips spaces:

```
def tokenization(x):
    res = []
    nmb = []
    for i in x:
        if i.isdigit() or i == '.':
            nmb.append(i)
        else:
            if len(nmb) > 0:
                ff = float(''.join(nmb))
                nmb = []
                res.append(ff)

            if i != ' ':
                res.append(i)

    if len(nmb) > 0:
        ff = float(''.join(nmb))
        res.append(ff)

    return res
```

So if you do:

```
tt = "(3.1+ 6*2∧2)*(2 - 1)"    
print(tokenization(tt))
```

this prints:

```
['(', 3.1, '+', 6.0, '*', 2.0, '∧', 2.0, ')', '*', '(', 2.0, '-', 1.0, ')']
```

Note that if you have an invalid float in the string (like `1.2.3`) this solution fails.